# VueJS Javascript Constructor

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have created a vue setup, where I import a custom Errors.js class that shall be instantiated in my Form class. But I get an error when loading the page:

> main.js:110 Uncaught TypeError:
>   __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2__helpers_Errors_js___default.a is not a constructor

Which I do not understand: Why is is not a constructor , when the constructor method is available in the Errors class?

```
import Errors from './helpers/Errors.js';

// IMPORT ADDONS
import VueEvents from 'vue-events';

window.Vue = Vue;
Vue.use(VueEvents)


class Form {
    constructor(data) {
        this.originalData = data;

        for (let field in data) {
            this[field] = data[field];
        }

        this.errors = new Errors();
    }
...
```

**ERRORS.js**

```
class Errors {
    constructor() {
        this.errors = {};
    }

    any() {
        return Object.keys(this.errors).length > 0;
    }

    get(field) {
        if(this.errors[field]) {
            return this.errors[field][0];
        }
    }

    record(errors) {
        this.errors = errors;
    }

    clear(field) {
        if(field) {
            this.errors[field];

            return;
        }
        this.errors = {};
    }
}
```

On top of that, I get an error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'props' of undefined`

I would assume this has something to do with the properties of my external class? But why?

Comment: Does `Errors.js` export anything?

Comment: Good point.. I changed to `export default class Errors` and the first error disappears, but the second remains.

Comment: I think that's somewhere else in your code. I don't see you trying to reference a `props` property anywhere here.